# How to debug the program that always keeps running in java (eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am the beginner for java, and have one program that keeps running without error report. Please help me how to debug this problem? I would like to use Scanner class to print one capital in random.

```
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
class SequenceChar{
private static Random rand  = new Random(47);
private static final char[] capitals = 
        "ABCDE".toCharArray();
char generate(){
    char buffer;
    int idx = 0;
    buffer = capitals[rand.nextInt(capiticals.length)];
    return buffer;
    }
}

public class C8 extends SequenceChar 
 implements Readable{
private int i;
public C8(int i){
    this.i = i;
}
public int read(CharBuffer ch){
    char buffer = generate();
    ch.put(buffer);

    return buffer;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner output  = new Scanner (new C8(103));

    System.out.println("begin");
    while(output.hasNext()){

        System.out.println(output.next());
    }
    System.out.println("end");


   }

 }
```

Comment: Look up "breakpoints".

Comment: Also http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/clocdbug.htm?cp=1_3_6_1

Answer (score 0):

```
while(output.hasNext())
```

Output.hasNext() is returning "True". Do not use a loop if you want to print just one word. Use "if" instead.

```
if(output.hasNext()){

        System.out.println(output.next());
    }
```